# StackPanel has a DataContext, how to populate ListPicker with option values from another?

Tags: data-binding, windows-phone-7, datacontext

I'm new to WP7 development, so binding is still a little foreign to me. I have a StackPanel that I've set the DataContext with TwoWay binding for editing a given record. But, within the "form" I have a ListPicker that I want to populate with possible values from a lookup table.

Currently I've created a DataTemplate and set the ItemsSource property of the ListPicker. Since the sole TextBlock in the DataTemplate is binding to the ItemsSource data context, how do I then bind the ListPicker's SelectedItem to the StackPanel's data context?

Answer (score 1):

Your object that you assign to StackPanel's DataContext must expose appropriate properties, for example:

```
class MyData
{
    public Data { get; set; }
    public Selected { get; set; }
}
```

Then you need to bind ListPicker's ItemsSource: `ItemsSource={Binding Data}` and ListPicker's SelectedItem: `SelectedItem={Binding Selected}`.

If you want ListPicker to react when you change MyData's Selected property you will need `MyData` class to implement interface `IObservable`. The same goes for `Data` property, this collection must inform when it's state changes, so make it of type: `ObservableCollection<ElemType>`.

Comment: IObjservable is generic... what type would he pass in?

class MyData : IObservable<?>{

}

Answer (score 0):

Check this: [Using the parent's DataContext (WPF - Dynamic Menu Command Binding)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998092/using-the-parents-datacontext-wpf)

Check all answers and see if one of them helps you.